# How to edit this code to include age groups in dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set which contains age groups that are numbered like this:

- 8 = 14 - 19
- 9 = 20 - 24

and so on.

I am trying to get four age groups into a line graph. I know that the part of the code I am using needs a few tweaks that I can't figure out.

I am using `ggplot` in RStudio.

I have tried changing this part:

```
  depression %>%
  filter(age>=15 & age <= 34) ->
  depression

depression$agecat <- cut(depression$age, c(14,19,25,30,35),
                         labels = c(" Females 15 to 19",
                                    " Females 20 to 24",
                                    " Females 25 to 29"
                                    " Females 30 to 34")`
```

To this without success :

```
  depression %>%
  filter(age>=8 & age <= 11) ->
  depression

depression$agecat <- cut(depression$age, c(8,9,10,11),
                         labels = c(" Females 15 to 19",
                                    " Females 20 to 24",
                                    " Females 25 to 29"
                                    " Females 30 to 34")`
```

full code is below:

```
  library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(ggpubr)


options(scipen=10000)

depression <- read.csv("depression 2.csv")
depression <- depression[depression$year>= 1990 & depression$year <= 2015,]


    depression %>%
  filter(age>=15 & age <= 34) ->
  depression

    depression$agecat <- cut(depression$age, c(14,19,25,30,35),
                         labels = c(" Females 15 to 19",
                                    " Females 20 to 24",
                                    " Females 25 to 29"
                                    " Females 30 to 34")
)
   depression %>% 
  filter(sex == 2)%>%
  group_by(year,agecat)%>%
  summarise(val = mean(val))%>%
  ggplot(aes(year, val, group = agecat, col = agecat))+
  geom_line()+
  theme_classic()
```

I already know it is these parts that are the problem:

```
filter(age>=15 & age <= 34) ->

depression$agecat <- cut(depression$age, c(14,19,25,30,35)
```

I am trying to achieve [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjgFT.jpg) (Image cannot be embedded, SO complains about the format).

Comment: Hi, what's going on with those [backticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) in you code? I don't know R, so maybe they are fine, but they certainly don't look right to me. Could you make sure that your code is free of typos and nicely formatted? That'll help others to focus on the actual problem.

Comment: Appreciated, removed.

Comment: Can you post a few rows of sample data?  `dput(head(depression))` is good if your data isn't sorted. If it is, maybe a different sample `dput(depression[c(1, 2, 20, 21, 40, 41), ]` or whatever rows are appropriate so we get a few different ages.

Comment: Also, please try to make the code you share minimal and relevant. We don't really need to see `depression <- read.csv("depression 2.csv")` since we dont' have your CSV file. It doesn't make sense for that to be in the middle of your code either... you work with the data at the top (implying it's already been read in), then you read it in in the middle. And delete the `theme` stuff, it is unrelated to this specific problem so it's just cluttering your question. And it's not used. You define `thm` but in the plot use the built-in `theme_classic`...

Comment: ok so I dont understand what you mean but I entered dput(head(depression) and this is what I have: > dput(head(depression))
structure(list(measure = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), location = c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), sex = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), age = c(8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L),

Comment: @dan86uk 1. Please edit your **question** with the results of `dput(head(depression))`. Unformatted output down in a comment is hard to read at the best of times, & in your case isn't even complete. 2. It sounds like you require the functionality of `factor()` with specified labels, not `cut()`.